# Solving requires an initial condition vector of length

Tags: matlab

I got the error "Solving CHIU requires an initial condition vector of length 651" when  running this Matlab file:

```
TSPAN = (0:1:320);
[ta,xa] = ode15s('Chiu',TSPAN,[0.0258 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5.88e9*exp(-701/(1.987*T)) 2.95e7*exp(-4353/(1.987*T)) 8.83]);
```

I really don't get what exactly this error means. What and where is the vector length 651? I only have 11 ODE equation. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I beieve, the first input to `ode15s` should be a functions handle, not the name of the function. So, instead of

```
[ta,xa] = ode15s('Chiu',TSPAN,...
```

try

```
[ta,xa] = ode15s(@Chiu,TSPAN,...
```